# Does angular momentum of our planetary spin explain the natural 'log e' explanation (the spiral pattern) of my fossil gastropod collection?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum

If so, where is the momentum conserved? Any shell may shatter if from a recent land or sea shell. Is a fossil the same way, just waiting for decompression?

Comment: uh... I'm really not sure what this is asking. What does angular momentum have to do with fossils? What's the "log e explanation"?

Comment: Rotation of the earth..maybe explains the spiral.

Comment: Could you please explain your question more? We are not geologist or biologist! What is the equation?

Comment: I am asking you to explain the equation to me please, for instance in the Northern hemisphere the rotation of the Earth determines a counter-clockwise spin on matter. Weather, ocean currents all are related in that spin. I wonder if my fossils preserve the original 'spin' of the earth's rotation and have a reserved momentum.

Answer (score 3):

The rotation of the Earth causes a force called the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect). This does have an effect on ocean currents, but the effect is only significant on length scales of hundreds of miles. Over the diameter of a shell, even a [big one](https://fangsandfossils.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/largest-ammonite-ever-discovered/), the Coriolis force is completely swamped by other effects like tides, local currents, random thermal fluctuations or whether a fish has just swum by.

So the answer is that no, the rotation of the Earth isn't an explanation for log shell growth.